# How can I get my sharedpreferences instance insise a worker

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, worker

I have a worker and want to access my shared preferences. In my worker class I can't do

```
this.getSharedPreferences
```

and

```
getSharedPreferences()
```

isn't static so I can't do

```
MainActivity.getSharedPreferences
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: You can call [`getApplicationContext()` on the `Worker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#getApplicationContext()) and from there get a `SharedPreferences`. Or, inject your `SharedPreferences` using your dependency inversion framework (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `getApplicationContext()` method directly from the Worker class to get the Context of the entire application, which should be reasonable in this use case.

Comment: static SharedPreferences is a bad idea because it might cause memory leaks

Comment: Thank you, I will try it :)